# Inserting data with PDO. I have tried so many ways and failed

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pdo, insert

I have just begun learning PDO.  I have connected to my database and I have a working login happening with the mySql database.  Now I am trying to get three pieces of data from a form and then insert them into the table.  I have been on this for a week and every version I come up with fails.  I get no error messages yet when I check the table it remains empty.

As I have other PDO action working, I'm confident that the problem is in the following piece of code.   The button involved is named 'addGig'.  This is the first time I have used the name of a button...  I'm not confident with this.

I have just edited this post to include my revised code. 
So many rookie mistakes!

```
       $date  = $_POST['date'];
       $venue = $_POST['venue'];
       $time  = $_POST['time'];

   if (!empty($date) && !empty($venue) && !empty($time)){

    try{
        $query = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO gigs (date, venue, time) VALUES (:date, :venue, :time)");
        $query->bindParam(':date' , $date);
        $query->bindParam(':venue' , $venue);
        $query->bindParam(':time' , $time);
        $query->execute(); 

       }

     catch(PDOException $e)
       {
       handle_sql_errors($query, $e->getMessage());
       }
  }
```

}

This is my html form

```
  <form>
  <label>date</label><br><input type="text" name="date"><br>
  <label>venue</label><br><input type="text" name="venue"><br>
  <label>time</label><br><input type="text" name="time"><br>
  <br>
  <button type="submit" value="addGig" name="addGig">add gig</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Read this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html and you will know why it failed. Plus, check for errors, which you're not doing.

Comment: I don't understand about error checking.  Should my code include something that shows me the errors?

Comment: See Marc's answer below.

Comment: I suggest you show us the HTML form you are using. Plus, your connection is PDO, right? This will take the guesswork out of everything ;-)

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. If your form does not contain name attributes, you will get an `Undefined index xxx` warning. Again, show us the HTML form.

Comment: I added the error reporting code you have provided. No errors..... hmm  Handy to know this though.   learning a lot from this post.

Comment: I'm sure my connection is good as I am able to login only with the correct user and pass which are both stored on the database.  I also have sessions working with a timeout thing.  I just double checked my connection and it is all in order.  Including the error handling!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here. (Now known after you posted your form code).

One of which is, that you are using `<form>` which defaults to GET when a method is not given. This in conjunction with your `$_POST` variables.

Therefore you need to give it a specific method, POST.

```
<form method="post">
```

Plus, without an action, defaults to self.

If you're using the form seperately from your SQL, you need to specify it.

I.e.:

```
<form method="post" action="handler.php">
```

Plus, you are/were using quotes for your columns. Remove them or using ticks.

Those aren't the right identifiers, as per your original question
https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28091236/2

```
('date', 'venue', 'time')
```

- **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html**

Comment: Just to double check --  action="handler.php"  refers to the page that my code resides?  it is included in the GUI page...

Comment: @user3545757 That was an example. If your form is called "form.html" and your SQL file is called "database.php" then name the action to that. Is your form and SQL all in one file?

Comment: No.  form is in GUI.php and the code is in gigUpdate.php  which is included in GUI.php.

Comment: Then do `<form action="gigUpdate.php" method="post">` then. @user3545757

Comment: Is it likely that the error could be in my database?  My login table works fine..

Comment: @user3545757 check your table's column names, their type, length, if you chose the correct DB, table. Could be anything. Add `$connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, see if that yields any errors.

Comment: I have already added  $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   i have no errors reported from this.

Comment: @user3545757 You said *"Now i go to gigUpdate.php which is blank and nothing to my db"* - You don't  "GO TO", you let the form do the action, not "you". Reload your form with the new action to the file, enter some data, and the action to your MySQL file `gigUpdate.php` will get there by itself. Also make sure you don't have cache problems.

Comment: @user3545757 I tested your code and was successful. For my test, my columns were all `VARCHAR(50)` and entered only words in there. If you're using any Javascript with that and you've not shown us, then I need to know. Judging from your inputs/column names, you are entering a DATE, then a VENUE being probable TEXT, then a DATE. Make sure you've chosen the correct column TYPES. I can't help you anymore than this, good luck with your project.

Comment: @user3545757 By the way, in your first code block, you have an extra closing brace `}` in `catch(PDOException $e)
       {
       handle_sql_errors($query, $e->getMessage());
       }
  }

}` <= that last one should be remove if there isn't another matching brace for it.

Comment: Thank you Fred.  (It was bedtime in Australia) I'm awake and looking into your suggestions. I bet you are right.

Comment: @user3545757 You're welcome. It's going to be bedtime here in about 2-3 hours lol

Answer (score 5):

You have ZERO error handling, and are simply assuming that your prepare could never fail. If you had error handling, you'd have been told about your syntax errors:

```
INSERT INTO gigs ('date', 'venue', 'time') 
                  ^----^--^-----^--^----^----
```

You've used the incorrect quotes. `'` turns things into string literals. You cannot use string literals as identifiers in MySQL. Identifiers (table/field names) must either be bare words, or quoted with backticks. Since none of your field names are reserved words, backticks are not required. But either of the following would be acceptable

```
INSERT INTO gigs (`date`, `venue`, `time`) 
INSERT INTO gigs (date, venue, time)
```

Comment: Assuming of course that the OP's form checks out ;-) *Ah*, the learning curve.

Comment: Thanks Marc.    This error handling must be important.  I will investigate.

Comment: Never ever assume success on operations involving external resources. There's exactly ONE way for them to succeed (they "just do"), and a near infinite number of ways for them to fail. It's basic defensive programming: always assume failure, check for that failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: Ha. Thanks Marc for lifting my spirits.  I  have put my code in a try/catch thing and using this -catch(PDOException $e)  {  handle_sql_errors($query, $e->getMessage());
           }

Comment: only if you enabled exception mode in PDO. by default it simply returns a boolean FALSE on failure.

Answer (score 3):

you have to edit your prepared statement into the right format:

> the columns in your database shouldn't be escaped with '.

```
"INSERT INTO gigs (date, venue, time) ...
```

you can write the prepared statement like this (for better reading):

```
...VALUES (:date, :venue, :time)...
```

In your bindParam Method you can assign your variables like this:

```
$query->bindParam(':date' , $date);
```

Or you do it like in your query:

```
...VALUES (?, ?, ?)...
```

and then:

```
$query->bindParam(1 , $date);
```

try this:

```
    $query = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO gigs (date, venue, time) VALUES (:date, :venue, :time)");
    $query->bindParam(':date' , $date);
    $query->bindParam(':venue' , $venue);
    $query->bindParam(':time' , $time);
    $query->execute();
```

for more information consult the manual:
http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Comment: So, tell the OP what's wrong with their code. Both methods are valid.

Comment: *"Second: the parameters in your query must contain a ':'."* [The manual](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) states `$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $name);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $value);` so again, both are valid.

Comment: Ok, I have formatted my code to match goldlifes example.  Still not working.  Right now I'm checking out this error handling situation.

Comment: oh yes you are right... :). I even always use my method with :parameter , and forget that this with ? and 1 is working too. I will edit this. So ... the problem in the OP query is the 'column_name' ... it has to be INSERT INTO gigs (column_name) without '.